# как исправить ошибки

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
struct graph_piece{
    public:
    std::string value;
    std::vector<graph_piece*> outcome;
    graph_piece(std::string,std::vector<graph_piece*>);
    std::vector<graph_piece> all_out();
};
graph_piece(std::string v,std::vector<graph_piece*> out){
    value = v;
    outcome = out;
};
std::vector<graph_piece> all_out(){
    std::vector<graph_piece> v;
    int i;
    graph_piece* cur;
    for(i = 0;i < outcome.size();i++){
        cur = outcome[i];
        v.push_back(*cur);
    };
    return v;
};
int main(){
    std::vector<graph_piece*> n;
    graph_piece a("big",n);
    n.push_back(&a);
    graph_piece* c = &a;
    graph_piece b("small",n);
    std::cout << b.value << "->" << b.all_out()[0].value;
    return 0;
};
```

**Но вот ошибки:**

```
[17:10:14] [Ошибки компиляции] [
C:/Users/1234/AppData/Local/Temp/CP Editor/sol.cpp:11:24: error: expected ')' before 'v'
   11 | graph_piece(std::string v,std::vector<graph_piece*> out){
      |            ~           ^~
      |                        )
C:/Users/1234/AppData/Local/Temp/CP Editor/sol.cpp: In function 'std::vector<graph_piece> all_out()':
C:/Users/1234/AppData/Local/Temp/CP Editor/sol.cpp:19:16: error: 'outcome' was not declared in this scope
   19 |  for(i = 0;i < outcome.size();i++){
      |                ^~~~~~~
]
```

**Поправил:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
struct graph_piece{
    public:
    std::string value;
    std::vector<graph_piece*> outcome;
    graph_piece(std::string,std::vector<graph_piece*>);
    std::vector<graph_piece> all_out();
};
graph_piece::graph_piece(std::string v,std::vector<graph_piece*> out){
    value = v;
    outcome = out;
};
std::vector<graph_piece> all_out(){
    std::vector<graph_piece> v;
    int i;
    graph_piece* cur;
    for(i = 0;i < outcome.size();i++){
        cur = outcome[i];
        v.push_back(*cur);
    };
    return v;
};
int main(){
    std::vector<graph_piece*> n;
    graph_piece a("big",n);
    n.push_back(&a);
    graph_piece* c = &a;
    graph_piece b("small",n);
    std::cout << b.value << "->" << b.all_out()[0].value;
    return 0;
};
```

**Но вот баг:**

```
C:/Users/1234/AppData/Local/Temp/CP Editor/sol.cpp: In function 'std::vector<graph_piece> all_out()':
C:/Users/1234/AppData/Local/Temp/CP Editor/sol.cpp:19:16: error: 'outcome' was not declared in this scope
   19 |  for(i = 0;i < outcome.size();i++){
      |                ^~~~~~~
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> graph_piece(std::string v,std::vector<graph_piece*> out){
> ```

```
graph_piece::graph_piece(std::string v,std::vector<graph_piece*> out){
```

Answer (score 0):

```
std::vector<graph_piece> graph_piece::all_out(){
```

а не

```
std::vector<graph_piece> all_out(){
```

**Вот как надо:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
struct graph_piece{
    public:
    std::string value;
    std::vector<graph_piece*> outcome;
    graph_piece(std::string,std::vector<graph_piece*>);
    std::vector<graph_piece> all_out();
};
graph_piece::graph_piece(std::string v,std::vector<graph_piece*> out){
    value = v;
    outcome = out;
};
std::vector<graph_piece> graph_piece::all_out(){
    std::vector<graph_piece> v;
    int i;
    graph_piece* cur;
    for(i = 0;i < outcome.size();i++){
        cur = outcome[i];
        v.push_back(*cur);
    };
    return v;
};
int main(){
    std::vector<graph_piece*> n;
    graph_piece a("big",n);
    n.push_back(&a);
    graph_piece* c = &a;
    graph_piece b("small",n);
    std::cout << b.value << "->" << b.all_out()[0].value;
    return 0;
};
```